# Magento 2 : How to Create Custom Header and Footer

Tags: magento2, theme, header, create

I am creating new header.phtml and footer.phtml and store into `app/design/frontend/<vendor_theme>/mytheme_name/theme_layout/template/html`.

so how to add new header and footer in magento/blank theme.

Answer (score 3):

You can overwrite the existing templates by copying them into your theme and making changes to the template files.

So copy these two files:

```
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/footer.phtml
```

Into your theme:

```
app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml
app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer.phtml
```

Comment: I am using a blank theme on how to add header and footer

Answer (score -1):

Change in xml

```
<default>
 <reference name="header">
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/Your_Custom_Header.phtml</template></action>
   </reference>
   <reference name="footer">
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/Your_Custom_Footer.phtml</template></action>
   </reference>
</default>
```

And

Placed Your_Custom_Header.phtml and Your_Custom_Footer.phtml in theme directory

```
app\design\frontend\Your_Theme\template\page\html\ Here
```

Comment: Your code is for Magento 1, the post is regarding Magento 2.

Comment: **Ooops sorry**